# Redirecting to specific homepages based on sign in with user role in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rolify

First off, I'm very new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails having only worked with them for a few days.  I'm currently trying to redirect the page a user lands on after signing in to a specific page based on their role and I'm not quite sure how to do it.  Does anyone know how I might approach this?  I've used the following links but can't get them to work.

I'm using Devise for authentication and Rolify for my roles.

This is my routes.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
    mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
    devise_for :admins
    devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
    devise_scope :user do
      authenticated :user do
        root :to => 'pages#videolibrary'
      end

  unauthenticated :user do
    root :to => 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

I've made a Passthrough controller but I don't know how to link the controller so that it's used.  Or even if this is the right way to approach this.

Here's the passthroughcontroller.rb:

```
class PassthroughController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if current_user.has_role? :admin
      redirect_to 'pages#videolibrary'
    elsif current_user.has_role? :retail
      redirect_to 'pages#retail'
    elsif current_user.has_role? :commercial
      redirect_to 'pages#commercial'
    elsif current_user.has_role? :business
      redirect_to 'pages#business'
    elsif current_user.has_role? :manager
      redirect_to 'pages#videolibrary'
    else
      redirect_to 'devise/registrations#new'
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried following these posts but have can't get it to work:

[Devise Redirects to specific page based on User Role on Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020473/devise-redirects-to-specific-page-based-on-user-role-on-login)

[How can I redirect a user's home (root) path based on their role using Devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753871/how-can-i-redirect-a-users-home-root-path-based-on-their-role-using-devise)

[how to change the rails root url based on the current user or role](http://minhajuddin.com/2011/10/24/how-to-change-the-rails-root-url-based-on-the-user-or-role)

Whit this link I don't have a role_constraint.rb file in my lib directory.

Maybe someone here has an idea on how to approach this?

**EDIT:**

I've updated my application controller to now read:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
      # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception

        before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
      protected
      def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)  { |u| u.permit(  :email, :password, :password_confirmation, role: []  ) }
      end

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      # Here you can write logic based on roles to return different after sign in paths
      if current_user.has_role? :admin
        get 'pages/videolibrary' => "pages#videolibrary", as: :retail_page
      elsif current_user.has_role? :retail
        get 'pages/retail' => "pages#commercial", as: :retail_page
      elsif current_user.has_role? :commercial
        get 'pages/commercial' => "pages#commercial", as: :commercial_page
      elsif current_user.has_role? :business
        get 'pages/business' => "pages#business", as: :business_page
      elsif current_user.has_role? :manager
        get 'pages/manager' => "pages#manager", as: :manager_page
      else
        get 'devise/registrations' => "devise/registrations#new"
      end
    end
end
```

And this is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :admins
devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'pages#videolibrary'
  end
  unauthenticated :user do
    root :to => 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
    get 'pages/welcome'
    get 'pages/home' => "pages#videolibrary"
    get 'videolibrary' => "pages#videolibrary"
    get 'pages/*page' => "pages#show"
    get 'pages/retail' => "pages#retail"
    get 'pages/commercial' => "pages#commercial"
    get 'pages/business' => "pages#business"
    get 'pages/manager' => "pages#manager"
  end
end
```

Here is my user.rb file if needed:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  resourcify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  ROLES = %w[admin retail commercial business manager]

end
```

And these are the revelant routes with rake routes:

```
                 root GET    /                               pages#videolibrary
 unauthenticated_root GET    /                               devise/registrations#new
        pages_welcome GET    /pages/welcome(.:format)        pages#welcome
           pages_home GET    /pages/home(.:format)           pages#home
         videolibrary GET    /videolibrary(.:format)         pages#videolibrary
                      GET    /pages/*page(.:format)          pages#show
          retail_page GET    /pages/retail(.:format)         pages#retail
      commercial_page GET    /pages/commercial(.:format)     pages#commercial
        business_page GET    /pages/business(.:format)       pages#business
         manager_page GET    /pages/manager(.:format)        pages#manager
```

I'm now getting a NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create

undefined method `get' for #Devise::SessionsController:0x9879660

```
    get 'pages/manager' => "pages#manager", as: :manager_page
  else
    get 'devise/registrations' => "devise/registrations#new"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise has a controller method you can override called `after_sign_in_path_for` this is talked about in the devise docs [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out). (The [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) and especially the how to examples are really helpful)

In your application controller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  # Here you can write logic based on roles to return different after sign in paths
  if current_user.has_role? :admin
    videolibrary_path
  elsif current_user.has_role? :retail
    retail_page_path
  elsif current_user.has_role? :commercial
    commercial_page_path
  elsif current_user.has_role? :business
    business_page_path
  elsif current_user.has_role? :manager
    videolibrary_path
  else
    new_user_path
  end
end
```

You will need to add the routes for the pages e.g

```
get 'pages/retail => "pages#retail", as: :retail_page # this sets up a named link 'retail_page_path' which you can use in controllers and views
```

Check out the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info. Also once you have written your routes you can run `rake routes` in the console to output all your apps routes as well as their named routes (like `retail_page_path`)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm now getting a new error, I've updated the post to reflect the error and pasted in relevant files (I think?).  I appreciate the help, would you happen to know what's giving me an error now?

Comment: The code you have included in your controller e.g `get 'pages/videolibrary' => "pages#videolibrary", as: :retail_page` is only for the routes.rb file. That code defines a route and basically says if someone asks for www.mysite.com/pages/videolibrary point them to the videolibrary action in the pages controller. It then makes a variable (named_route) called retail_page_path that links to that url.

If you remove the routes code from the controller and replace it with each corresponding named route it should hopefully work!

Comment: So just to clarify, in my answer above when I wrote `commercial_page_path` for example I don't mean to replace that with the commercial page path I mean keep `commercial_page_path` there as it is a  named route which inserts the correct path itself. Try just copying that whole method.